# Display previous and next data using Laravel PHP

Tags: laravel

How can I write code to display the output as shown below using Laravel:

```
result : [
  login: {

  },
  pause:{

  },
  restart:{

  },
  logout:{

  },
  login:{

  },.....
]
```

Comment: you can use json: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/responses

Comment: try using : `{{ dd(json_encode(collect([['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3]]))) }}`

Answer (score 0):

simply try with

```
 $data['login'] = array(data);
 $data['pause'] = array(data);
 $data['reset'] = array(data); etc
```

and try with echo json_encode($data); or response()->json($data);